# Asus Xonar DS - How do I get Ubuntu to run my Sound Card?

Tags: sound, soundcard, peripherals

I have a Razer Tiamat 7.1 and some 2.1 speakers. I have found the drivers for my sound card but not for Ubuntu. Is there a method of installing them?

Sorry I am new to the 15.1 version of Ubuntu, my only experience is a long time ago in 11/12 IIRC.

Comment: For which distribution have you found them? Can you provide more information (e.g. post link)?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes pre-installed with drivers , asus card is well supported so you don't need any extra drivers for that ,it is plug n play ,but you do have to select this sound card  in Sound Settings to tell system to use this card and not default one.